# Why doesn't notice work with action in redirect_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This works:

```
redirect_to admins_path, email: @user.email, notice: 'Success'
```

But this does not set the notice:

```
redirect_to action: 'show', email: @user.email, notice: 'Success'
```

Why does setting the action suppress the notice?

Rails 4.1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the why, but if you look at the example [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to), you'll see you have to write it (I think)

```
redirect_to ({action: 'show', email: @user.email}, notice: 'Success')
```

If I had to guess, the admins_path creates the required hash, whereas when you do it manually you must create the hash.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I have to ask - is there a reason you can't just user redirect_to @user?

Answer (score 1):

`redirect_to` takes either a string or a hash for its first parameter. In the first case, a hash containing email and notice are sent as the second parameter, but in the second case, the hash is divided somewhat arbitrarily into two hashes order to satisfy the parameter list of the method:

```
redirect_to admins_path, email: @user.email, notice: 'Success'
```

is equivalent to

```
redirect_to admins_path, {email: @user.email, notice: 'Success'}
```

and

```
redirect_to action: 'show', email: @user.email, notice: 'Success'
```

is equivalent to

```
redirect_to {action: 'show'}, {email: @user.email, notice: 'Success'}
```

when what you want is

```
redirect_to {action: 'show', email: @user.email}, notice: 'Success'
```

Comment: Actually, `{action: 'show'}, email: @user.email, notice: 'Success'` does not work. The email has to be in the first hash. Without curly braces, I think Ruby coerces all but the first param into the 2nd hash.

Comment: I see - so if the method takes two params, ruby will divide up an ambiguous hash by 'guessing' that the first hash element is the first param - good to know!

Comment: modified my answer accordingly

Comment: Yes, I think so. That's one of the stinky things about default params.